# Need the whole PHPExcel project for dynamically generated Excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel, dynamically-generated

Just curious about the requirements for the whole PHPExcel project when you want to create a simple dynamically generated Excel file that doesn't exceed more than 125 lines , i'm generating a report of names and stats that go along with these names on my site, although it takes around 15-20 seconds to generate it after you click the button, which is far too long.

Just wondering if you need the whole project to do this or can you(so to speak)trim the fat to make it quicker ?

Any help would be much appreciated

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $data = Factory_Company::getForAdminCompaniesPage(array(
                "pageSize" => 10000,
                "page" => 0
    ));

    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A1:J1")->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:A1');

    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Stackover")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("john smith")
            ->setTitle("Test Agency List")
            ->setSubject("Test Agency List")
            ->setDescription("Test Agency List")
            ->setKeywords("Test Agency Excel List")
            ->setCategory("Test Agency");



    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'Agency')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'Date Added')
            ->setCellValue('C1', '# of jobs')
            ->setCellValue('D1', '# of candidates')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'Location')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'Email')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'Contact Name')
            ->setCellValue('H1', 'Last Logged in')
            ->setCellValue('I1', 'Sales Rep')
            ->setCellValue('J1', 'Active/Inactive');
    $rowID = 2;
    foreach ($data as $rowArray) {
        $columnID = 'A';
        foreach ($rowArray as $columnValue) {
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID . $rowID, $columnValue);
            $columnID++;
        }
        $rowID++;
    }


    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Intalex Agency List');


    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Agencies.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
    header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
}
```

}

Comment: How much fat do you want trimming? If you're not reading files, you don't need the Readers, if you're only generating one output format, then you only need a subset of Writers... but simply removing a few files from the distribution won't affect speed in any way

Comment: But one of the beautiful things about Open Source is that you can actually edit the code if you want to eliminate anything that you don't need

Comment: I knew that you could remove all the files you don't need, it is just that every time i remove files i receive errors, what is the best way to improve speed @MarkBaker

Comment: Use fromArray() rather than individually setting each cell; if you're using styles, make sure you set styles for ranges of cells where you can rather than for individual cells; show your code if you want anything more than those simple generic suggestions

Comment: i think the one thing that may be slowing it down is the double foreach, heres the code :)

Comment: That's where using the `fromArray()` method is recommended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eliminate the nested foreach loop by changing

```
foreach ($data as $rowArray) {
    $columnID = 'A';
    foreach ($rowArray as $columnValue) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($columnID . $rowID, $columnValue);
        $columnID++;
    }
    $rowID++;
}
```

to

```
foreach ($data as $rowArray) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($rowArray, null, 'A'. $rowID++);
}
```

or even simply

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($data, null, 'A2');
```

And eliminate

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setAutoFilter('A1:A1');
```

because it's meaningless setting autofiltering on a single cell, but will add overhead

Comment: Thanks @MarkBaker , no better help than the creator , impressive how much you reply to answers on SOF ! :) if i have any more questions ill be sure to be back !

Comment: Another question , what if i wanted to have data generate in a certain column, how would i do that as i am having difficulty achieving that at the moment @MarkBaker

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, can you ask a fresh question showing what you want to do here

Comment: i figured it :) just one last thing though , all or most of the columns are bigger than the cells, how do i auto size them to what content goes in them, or even set individual columns to certain widths ?

Comment: Section 4.6.28 of the Developer Documentation: `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('B')->setAutoSize(true);` ... and you have to set this for each column individually, it doesn't accept a range like 'B:F'

Comment: Thanks ! great customer support ;)